# Multidimensional array problem in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fill a three dimensional array in JavaScript, but I get an error message in the web borwser console.

Here are the program step :

• opens a JSON array, based on this structure :
[image: Array structure]
• creates the tableau_ouverture array in 3D :
○ the fisrt dimension is the lens number ;
○ the second dimension is the aperture value ;
○ the third dimension stores the paths of three images, related to this aperture and this lens.
• reads the JSON array and is supposed to fill the tableau_ouverture array with the data.

```
// Lit le fichier .json pour trouver le nombre d'objectifs dans la liste.

$.getJSON("includes/comparaison-objectifs.json", function (data) {
  // Redimensionne les tableaux créés plus haut pour en faire des tableaux à deux dimensions : l'indice "i" correspond au numéro de l'objectif, la seconde dimension contient la valeur d'ouverture, les images "center", "middle" et "corner" de cette ouverture.

  var tableau_ouverture = [];
  tableau_ouverture[0] = [];
  tableau_ouverture[0][0] = [];
  tableau_ouverture[0][0][0] = [];

  // Lit le fichier .json pour établir la liste des objectifs.
  for (l in data.OBJECTIFS) {
    if (data.OBJECTIFS[l].PUBLICATION == "o") {
      //Si l'objectif est publié,...

      compteur_ouvertures = 0; //Réinitialise à 0 le compteur des ouvertures pour ce nouvel objectif.

      if (data.OBJECTIFS[l].f1 != "") {
        tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures] = data.OBJECTIFS[l].f1; //Stocke la valeur de l'ouverture.

        //Stocke les chemins vers les images "center", "middle" et "corner" pour cette ouverture.
        tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures][0] =
          "comparaison-objectifs/" +
          tableau_objectifs_reference[l] +
          "/center-" +
          data.OBJECTIFS[l].f1 +
          ".jpg";
        tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures][1] =
          "comparaison-objectifs/" +
          tableau_objectifs_reference[l] +
          "/middle-" +
          data.OBJECTIFS[l].f1 +
          ".jpg";
        tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures][2] =
          "comparaison-objectifs/" +
          tableau_objectifs_reference[l] +
          "/corner-" +
          data.OBJECTIFS[l].f1 +
          ".jpg";

        compteur_ouvertures++; //Incrémente le compteur des ouvertures pour passer à une éventuelle autre ouverture au test suivant.
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I get an error message at the line :

```
tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures] = data.OBJECTIFS[l].f1;
```

Can anyone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should initialize `tableau_ouverture[l] = []` right before the error line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used another approach. Instead of redimensioning the table, I used the "push" method to add entries to the table :

```
compteur_ouvertures = 0; //Réinitialise à 0 le compteur des ouvertures pour ce nouvel objectif.
var fnr = "f" + (compteur_ouvertures + 1);

while (data.OBJECTIFS[l].hasOwnProperty(fnr) && data.OBJECTIFS[l][fnr] != "")
{
  var fval = data.OBJECTIFS[l][fnr]
  tableau_objectifs.push([data.OBJECTIFS[l].OBJECTIFREFERENCE + "-" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].MONTUREREFERENCE + "-" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].APPAREILREFERENCE, data.OBJECTIFS[l].OBJECTIFNOM, data.OBJECTIFS[l].MONTURENOM, data.OBJECTIFS[l].APPAREILNOM, ouverture, "comparaison-objectifs/" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].OBJECTIFREFERENCE + "-" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].MONTUREREFERENCE + "-" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].APPAREILREFERENCE + "/center-" + ouverture + ".jpg", "comparaison-objectifs/" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].OBJECTIFREFERENCE + "-" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].MONTUREREFERENCE + "-" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].APPAREILREFERENCE + "/middle-" + ouverture + ".jpg", "comparaison-objectifs/" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].OBJECTIFREFERENCE + "-" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].MONTUREREFERENCE + "-" + data.OBJECTIFS[l].APPAREILREFERENCE + "/corner-" + ouverture + ".jpg"]);

  compteur_ouvertures++;
  fnr = "f" + (compteur_ouvertures + 1);
}
```

Thus, whatever the number of columns the program needs to add, the table is redimensioned automatically.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. variable `fnr` should be f1, f2, f3, ... This is done in a while until you run out of 'f' or is empty.

```
compteur_ouvertures = 0; //Réinitialise à 0 le compteur des ouvertures pour ce nouvel objectif.
var fnr = "f" + (compteur_ouvertures + 1);

while (data.OBJECTIFS[l].hasOwnProperty(fnr) && data.OBJECTIFS[l][fnr] != "")
{
  var fval = data.OBJECTIFS[l][fnr]
  var ref = tableau_objectifs_reference[l];
  tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures] = []; // or array();
  //Stocke les chemins vers les images "center", "middle" et "corner" pour cette ouverture.
  tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures][0] =
    "comparaison-objectifs/" + ref + "/center-" + fval + ".jpg";
  tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures][1] =
    "comparaison-objectifs/" + ref + "/middle-" + fval + ".jpg";
  tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures][2] =
    "comparaison-objectifs/" + ref + "/corner-" + fval + ".jpg";

  compteur_ouvertures++;
  fnr = "f" + (compteur_ouvertures + 1);
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your detailed reply!
I copied/pasted you code into my web page but I got the same error message :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')
    at Object.success (comparaison-objectifs.html:165)
    at fire (jquery-2.1.3.js:3094)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.3.js:3206)
    at done (jquery-2.1.3.js:8259)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.3.js:8600)`

The problem is on the code line :
`tableau_ouverture[l][compteur_ouvertures] = []; // or array();`

Any tip?